# Huh? That's a word?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, lateral-thinking

I am a word with 6 letters.

I contain a "la" in the middle, in in the beginning, and at the end.

What am I?

Comment: "in in the beginning" -> part of the puzzle or typo?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 hmmmm...what do you think?

Comment: I applaud your commitment to solving the problem in [this currently hot meta question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6169/does-the-current-puzzle-answering-format-discourage-some-solvers?cb=1) :-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Phrasing and punctuation is crucial in wordplay puzzles, and I'm not sure if I agree with the particular ones used here.

However, my guess is

> inland

which kind of works, because

> "la" is the middle, "in" the beginning, "and" the end.

Comment: If I were to use commas, this problem would be too easy :)))

Answer (score 23):

I think it is

> inland

because

> la is in the middle, in is in the beginning, and and is at the end.

Comment: Sorry LifesavingLinen but I just realized that @Bass posted before you did.

Answer (score 14):

I'm going to post an **`incorrect answer`** without hiding it so no one feels the need to re-post this answer. :))))

I think the answer is "lalala".

Comment: @NL628 Sorry but this is not correct. :)

Comment: I have another :)

Answer (score 6):

Another incorrect answer:

> SCALES

because

> *do re mi fa sol **LA** ti do*, and there are *[modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(music))* which have the LA at the beginning, and at the end, and (the other five) in the middle.

Comment: yess even better than mine

Comment: This is better than the correct answer, as it doesn't depend on misinterpreting grammar and punctuation.

Answer (score 6):

The correct answer already got accepted,this is just a try

> INLAIN

It contains

> "LA" in the middle, "IN" the beginning and at the end.

The title : Huh? That's a word?

> I am also asking, is that a word. :P

Comment: A major difficulty is the improbability of the verb *inlie* whose past participle this would be.

Comment: @Kaz Improbable or not this gets used in art, construction, and craftsman circles. It might not even be officially correct but it does see some use.

Comment: @Caleb Are you sure you're not, rather, thinking of *inlay*?

Comment: @Kaz That would be the (admittedly much more common) noun form, not the (also sometimes used) past participle form.

Comment: @Caleb it seems to be an incorrect or at leaset almost-never-used version of the past participle. I only know it as a regular verb, and ngrams say the same: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inlain%2C+inlaid&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinlain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinlaid%3B%2Cc0.

Comment: @Caleb I mean *to inlay* which goes to *inlaid*.